# Some questions about how proper add 2 CSS file in a WordPress theme?

Tags: functions, theme-development, themes, css, wp-enqueue-style

I have the following situation loading a CSS.

I have a WordPress theme that load a **style.css** settings file by this code into my **functions.php** file:

```
/* Function automatically executed by the hook:
 * 1) (OPTIONAL): Register a script (without load it): in this case register the CSS settings
 * 2) Load the CSS settings

 */
function wpb_adding_styles() {
    wp_register_style('my_stylesheet', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('my_stylesheet');
}

/* Hooks a function on to a specific action (an action is a PHP function that is executed at specific
 * points throughout the WordPress Core)
 * @param 'wp_enqueue_scripts': The name of the action to which 'wpb_adding_styles' is hooked (wp_enqueue_scripts
 *        is the proper hook to use when enqueuing items that are meant to appear on the front end)
 */
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpb_adding_styles');
```

In this **style.css** file I define some basic CSS configuration, for example the body settings:

```
body{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

Then I have create a new **style2.css** settings file in which I would override\add some of the properties defined into my general **style.css**, following the previous example I would add the property that the body background have to be black, something like it:

```
body {
    ........
    ........
    ........
    background: #000;
}
```

Ok, so I think that I need to load the **style.css** file using the **style2.css** file as its dependencies, reading the documentation it seems to me that I can do something like it (or maybe the opposite?):

```
function load_theme_styles() { 
    wp_enqueue_style('main-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_theme_styles');
```

where array() should not be empty but it have to contain the **style2.css**

Is it a good solution to keep separate a general CSS file that have not to be edited (for example a css file of a CSS framework such as BootStrap with its original settings) and the have a custom CSS file in wich I override the settings that I want to change?

If this is a goog solution can you say me how to pass in the previous array my **style2.css** file?

UPDATE 1: I have change my **wpb_adding_styles()** in this way: my **main-css** depends from **style2.css**.

```
function wpb_adding_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_style('style2', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style2.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('main-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array('style2'), '1.0', 'all');

}
```

It seems work well but I am not sure if it is the right solution because if I delete the dependency it work well again

```
wp_enqueue_style('main-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');
```

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're using dependencies the opposite way of how they should be used.

In the [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style), they try to explain how it's supposed to be used.

> **$deps** *(array) (optional)*
>
> Array of handles of any stylesheets that this
>   stylesheet depends on. **Dependent stylesheets will be loaded before
>   this stylesheet**.

Since your `style2.css` is used to make changes to `style.css`, it means `style2.css` is dependent on `style.css`.

This is what your code should look like:

```
function wpb_adding_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_style('main-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('style2', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style2.css', array('main-css'), '1.0', 'all');
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Perfect explaination !!!

Answer (score 1):

The array should contain the *handle* for style2.css.
When you enqueue the first style, you are using main-css, but you had to define that handle beforehand.

Working with inheritance and overwriting in css is a good workflow yes. Especially with frameworks like boostrap. That is the whole point of it. You've got a wonderful base which you can easily extend or modify where needed.

It becomes all the better when you use a tool such as SASS because the css file you include is now all jammed into a single compressed file.
http://sass-lang.com/

Cheers

Comment: I have edit my previous post inserting some additional information about what I have do ad the end, can you chek it and say me if it is ok?

Comment: array('style2').

Comment: ok but why it work well also if I not insert any dependency in the array of the main css?

Comment: Because main.css is not dependent on anything.

Comment: mmm I am bit confused, can you give me an example in which I need to set that a CSS depends from another CSS?